# onDownload complete notification

Tags: android

Is there a piece of code I could write to be notified when a download finishes in android, and  be able to execute some custom actions on this event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A download of...what?

If you are downloading via your own code (`HttpUrlConnection` or `HttpClient`), you know when the download is complete.

If you are using `WebView` and want to know when the page is loaded, you can use a `WebViewClient` to be notified of that event.

If the user is using the Browser application or a third-party browser, you cannot "be notified when a download finishes" in general. If you are set up to be a handler of that MIME type, and if the user chooses to open the file in your `ACTION_VIEW` activity, then you will be "notified" by your activity starting up.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify that. I want to be notified when the android browser downloads something.

Comment: Could you be more specific on that ? .Where should I set up a handler ? , and when will this handler will be called ?

Comment: If you are trying to create a handler for a particular MIME type, you need to create an activity with an intent-filter that specifies the MIME type and the ACTION_VIEW action. There are examples of this in the Android source code. Your activity will then be an option for the user for opening the downloaded file.

Comment: I got the idea , unfortunately it's not fit for my use

Comment: You cannot otherwise be notified of Browser downloads -- that would be a privacy violation.